# Unity3D - Error saying Unexpected symbol `extends'

Tags: javascript, c#, unity-game-engine, inheritance, extends

Unity3D 2018.1.6

The script was originally javascript but converted it to csharp. Now I have an error for the class saying its unexpected that I used `extends'

Error

> Unexpected symbol `extends'

I tried 2 ways of using `extends` as javascript had it, for example

First Way 1)

```
public class ScriptOne : MonoBehaviour {
    //
}
class ScriptOne extends Object {
    //
}
```

Second Way 2)

```
public class ScriptTwo extends Object : MonoBehaviour {
    //
}
```

Both ways gave me the same error.

Here is one of the scripts that was converted from .js to .cs

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class OrbitState extends Object : MonoBehaviour {


//================================//
//===   Orbit State datatype   ===//
//================================//

/*
 The OrbitState is the initial state of the orbiter at a particular point along the ellipse
 The state contains all of the information necessary to apply a force to get the orbiter moving along the ellipse
*/

Vector3 position; // local position relative to the object we're orbiting around
Vector3 normal;
Vector3 tangent;
Vector3 velocity;
private Orbiter orbiter;
private OrbitalEllipse ellipse; 

//==== Instance Methods ====//

// Constructor
void  OrbitState ( float angle ,   Orbiter orbiter ,   OrbitalEllipse ellipse  )
{
    Update(angle, orbiter, ellipse);
}

// Update the state of the orbiter when its position along the ellipse changes
// Note: Make sure the ellipse is up to date before updating the orbit state
void  Update ( float orbiterAngle ,   Orbiter orbiter ,   OrbitalEllipse ellipse  )
{
    this.orbiter = orbiter;
    this.ellipse = ellipse;
    this.normal = CalcNormal(orbiterAngle);
    this.tangent = CalcTangent(normal);
    this.position = ellipse.GetPosition(orbiterAngle, orbiter.orbitAround.position);
    this.velocity = CalcVelocity(orbiter.orbitSpeed * orbiter.GravityConstant(), position, orbiter.orbitAround.position);
}


//==== Private Methods ====//

// Returns the normal on the ellipse at the given angle
// Assumes a vertical semi-major axis, and a rotation of 0 at the top of the ellipse, going clockwise
private Vector3 CalcNormal ( float rotationAngle  )
{
    // Part 1: Find the normal for the orbiter at its starting angle
    // Rotate an upward vector by the given starting angle around the ellipse. Gives us the normal for a circle.
    Vector3 localNormal = Quaternion.AngleAxis(rotationAngle, Vector3.forward*-1) * Vector3.up;
    // Sqash the normal into the shape of the ellipse
    localNormal.x *= ellipse.semiMajorAxis/ellipse.semiMinorAxis;

    // Part 2: Find the global rotation of the ellipse
    float ellipseAngle = Vector3.Angle(Vector3.up, ellipse.difference);
    if (ellipse.difference.x < 0)
        ellipseAngle = 360-ellipseAngle; // Full 360 degrees, rather than doubling back after 180 degrees

    // Part 3: Rotate our normal to match the rotation of the ellipse
    Vector3 globalNormal = Quaternion.AngleAxis(ellipseAngle, Vector3.forward*-1) * localNormal;
    return globalNormal.normalized;
}

private Vector3 CalcTangent ( Vector3 normal  )
{
    float angle = 90;
    int direction = orbiter.counterclockwise ? -1 : 1;
    FIXME_VAR_TYPE tangent= Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle*direction, Vector3.forward*-1) * normal;
    return tangent;
}

private Vector3 CalcVelocity ( float gravity ,   Vector3 orbiterPos ,   Vector3 orbitAroundPos  )
{
    // Vis Viva equation
    float speed = Mathf.Sqrt( gravity * (2/Vector3.Distance(orbiterPos, orbitAroundPos) - 1/ellipse.semiMajorAxis ) );
    Vector3 velocityVec = tangent * speed;
    return velocityVec;
}
}
```

I have a second script with the same error but in solving one script I'm sure I can solve the other.

Thank you for the help!

Comment: It would be better to link us to the original Javascript code or post it here too

Comment: Unless i've missed something, extends is not a C# keyword

Comment: @PassetCronUs http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Simple_planetary_orbits here you go

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The equivalent of `extends` keyword is `:` in C#.

**UnityScript**:

```
class OrbitState extends Object { //your code}
```

**C#**:

```
class OrbitState : UnityEngine.Object { //your code}`
```

Note that I added `UnityEngine` namespace because there is `System.Object`. That is a different one.

---

**UnityScript**:

```
class OrbitalEllipse extends Object {}
```

**C#**:

```
class OrbitalEllipse : UnityEngine.Object { }
```

---

For other scripts in that [project](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/Simple_planetary_orbits) that didn't use the `extend` keyword, they simply derive from `MonoBehaviour` when converted to C#.

For example:

```
class OtherScripts : MonoBehaviour { }
```

Answer (score 1):

Extends is a Java keyword. Not C# nor JavaScript.

In C# you use the colon to say extends in Java you use the word.

You can't use JavaScript or Java when writing C# code.

```
public class OrbitState extends Object : MonoBehaviour {
```

Should be

```
public class OrbitState : MonoBehaviour {
```

Comment: So I don't need to say `: Object` ? `: MonoBehavior` is enough?

Comment: Correct.You can only extend from one class in C#.

Comment: Should be `class OrbitState : Object` not `class OrbitState : MonoBehaviour`